# 変数に対して一度に同じクラスのインスタンスを代入したい

Tags: smalltalk

変数に対して同じクラスのインスタンスをセットする必要が出てきたとき、下のように泥臭いコードになってしまいます:

```
a1 := TestClass new.
a2 := TestClass new.
a3 := TestClass new.
a4 := TestClass new.
```

このように書いてしまうと、同じクラスのインスタンスを代入する行がずっと続くことになり、非常に汚ないように感じてしまいます。もし、このように変数に対して、同じクラスのインスタンスをそれぞれに代入する方法があれば、教えてください。

Comment: `compound assignment` はどうでしょうか。`a1 := a2 := a3 := a4 := TestClass new.` まぁこれもあまりキレイとは言えませんが…

Comment: @argus 同じオブジェクトを代入するというのは質問者の意図と違うと思います。(普通ならば配列などを使う場面に見えます)

Comment: @mjy というわけで `#('a1' 'a2' 'a3' 'a4') do: [:v | Behavior evaluate: v, ' := TestClass new'].` を思い付いたのですが scope の関係でダメで、`a1 := (a2 := (a3 := (a4 := TestClass new) copy) copy) copy` になると無理やり感があるのでよろしくないですね…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

おそらくこういうことだと思うのですが、こうするのがスマートかどうかは微妙ですね。Squeak/Pharo Smalltalk で動作します。

```
| a1 a2 a3 a4 |
a1 := a2 := a3 := a4 := nil. "コンパイル時の警告抑止のため"
#(a1 a2 a3 a4) do: [:tName |
   | ctxt tNames |
   ctxt := thisContext outerContext.
   tNames := ctxt tempNames.
   ctxt tempAt: (tNames indexOf: tName) put: tName "実際はTestClass new"
].
^{a1. a2. a3. a4} "=> #(#a1 #a2 #a3 #a4) "
```

---

使える変数の数にも限りがあるので、上の @mjy さんのコメントにもありますが、ひとつのコンテキストで扱うオブジェクトの数が増えてきたら、ひとつひとつを変数にアサインせずに済む方法を考えるのもよいかもしれません。

たとえばゲートの組み合わせて回路を構築するような場面であれば、回路をオブジェクトにしてそれに追加するゲート（名前を付けられるようにしておく）を管理させたり、あるいは各ゲートのクラスに allInstances で手繰らせるという手もあります。言うまでもなく、名前の衝突については要注意ですが…。

```
NotGate class >> named: gateName
   ^self allInstances
    detect: [:gate | gate name = gateName]
    ifNone: [self new setName: gateName; yourself]
```

Squeak/Pharo Smalltalk であれば、named: を implementers of it (alt/cmd + m) して同名メソッドの定義を一覧すると、（そう多くはないですが）その手の管理方法をとっているオブジェクトの例が見つかるので参考にしてみてください。